# Easiest way to run a PHP script without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list with values.

example:

- 1
- 2
- 3

If I click on 1 value I want to run a PHP script which updates the value with the last clicked number.

I have:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="add('<?php echo $subiid ?>'); return false" title="add"><?php echo $subiid ?></a>
```

Where subiid is the value to be posted

in my header I have the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toevoegenFavo(aid) {
  alert(aid);
}
</script>
```

Which shows an alert box with the right value.

What I want to do is when I click on the value it will be posted to a PHP script, to update the database.

What is the best way JavaScript, AJAX, jQuery?

**Solution**

```
function toevoegenFavo(aid) {

alert("the picture is added");
$.post("favoriet.php", { aid: aid } );
}
```

Comment: Have you read ajax?????????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a callback to .onclick of all list elements and -

```
$.post("test.php", { name: 'valueWhichYouWannaSend', time: "2pm" } );
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
First argument is the url and second argument contains the data(as a object) you want to send